# Monitor a hard disk partition

Tags: monitoring, disk-usage

I need to monitor a partition on a CentOS server (`/`, to be exact) and would like to be alerted when it is full or full to a certain percentage.

What is a simple way (using built-in tools) to accomplish this?

Comment: installing Nagios to your machine can detect this

Comment: There are many different ways to accomplish this - if you're looking for a pre-canned solution, this might be better off on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Not exactly built-in, but you could just write a bash script to check the percentage used using df, awk the appropriate column, and then put it on a cron.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bash script called 'lvm-usage' [here](http://www.timedicer.co.uk/programs/help/lvm-usage.sh.php) (or google for it). Ensure that you receive text output from cron jobs (e.g. by mail), then set a regular cron job running `lvm-usage.sh -q 80`, you will be notified if any of your partitions are more than 80% full. (Despite the name, it doesn't require LVM).